# Rails Upgrade makes default Time format change. How to revert?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am upgrading a Rails app from

- Rails 4.2 -> 5.2 (a subsequent upgrade to Rails 6 is pending)
- Ruby 2.2 -> 2.5
- Postgres 9.1 -> 10

in various steps. Since the Rails upgrade requires the Postgres upgrade I can't separate the upgrades in a sensible way.

Currently I am struggling with the way "Time" objects are handled in Rails 5.2. A "time" column in an AR object is now returned as an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, even if the database column has no time zone. Previously it was a plain `Time` object which had a different default JSON representation.

This makes a lot of API tests fail which were previously all returning UTC times.

Example for Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.2, PG 9.1 for a `PhoneNumber` object:

```
2.2.6 :002 > p.time_weekdays_from
  => 2000-01-01 07:00:00 UTC 
2.2.6 :003 > p.time_weekdays_from.class
  => Time
```

Example for Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.5, PG 10:

```
irb(main):016:0> p.time_weekdays_from
  => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 11:15:00 CET +01:00
irb(main):018:0> p.time_weekdays_from.class
  => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

I have added an initializer to override this for the time being and this seems to work fine, but I'd nevertheless like to understnand **why** this change has been made and why even 'time without time zone' DB columns are being treated by Rails as if they had a timezone.

```
# This works, but why is it necessary?
module ActiveSupport
  class TimeWithZone
    def as_json(options = nil)
      self.utc.iso8601
    end
  end
end
```

PS: I don't always want UTC, I just want it for the API because that's what our API clients expect.

Comment: The change makes more sense if you consider DBs without a separate time with zone column type. There is makes sense for rails to provide a sensible default and assume that the timestamps are in the same zone as what is configured by Rails.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the issue [TimeWithZone#as_json 5.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb#L167) is identical to  [Time#as_json 4.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb#L164) It is nearly copy and paste code, so there should be no difference. If you always want utc then set the time_zone to UTC (e.g. `Time.zone = 'UTC'`)

Comment: Rails always save the time in UTC to the database no matter what time zone you have set in the application. Then every time you read time from the database it gets translated to the currently set time zone in you rails app.

Comment: edariedl, this did not happen in Rails 4.2 with "Time" columns. They were timezone-less. Now, in Rails 5, it suddenly happens. I did not find any deprecation warnings or upgrade notices about this. This is what bugs me. Good thing we have good test coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently I am struggling with the way "Time" objects are handled in Rails 5.2. A "time" column in an AR object is now returned as an ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, even if the database column has no time zone. Previously it was a plain Time object which had a different default JSON representation.
>
> I'd nevertheless like to understnand why this change has been made and why even 'time without time zone' DB columns are being treated by Rails as if they had a timezone.

This change was made because Ruby's default `Time` has no understanding of time zones. `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` can. This solves a lot of problems when working with times, time zones, and databases.

For example, let's say your application's time zone is `America/Chicago`. Previously you had to decide whether you're going to store your times with or without time zones. If you opt for without a time zone, do you store it as UTC or as America/Chicago? If you store it as UTC, do you convert it to America/New York on load or on display? Conversion means adding and subtracting hours from the `Time`. When you save `Time` objects you have to be careful to remember what time zone the `Time` was converted to and to convert it back to the database's time zone. Coordinating all this leads to many bugs.

Rails 5 introduces `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. This stores the time as UTC and the desired time zone to represent it in. Now handling time is simpler: store it as UTC (ie. `timestamp`) and add the application's time zone on load. No conversion is necessary. Rails handles this for you.

The change is now `timestamp` columns, by default, will be formatted in the application's time zone. This takes some getting used to, but ultimately will make your handling of times and time zones more robust.

```
> Time.zone.tzinfo.name
=> "America/Chicago"

> Time.zone.utc_offset
=> -21600

# Displayed in the application time zone
> Foo.last.created_at
=> Tue, 31 Dec 2019 17:16:14 CST -06:00

# Stored as UTC
> Foo.last.created_at.utc
=> 2019-12-31 23:16:14 UTC
```

If you have code which manually does time zone conversions, get rid of it. Work in UTC. Time zones are now just formatting.

As much as possible...

- Work with objects, not strings.
- Work in UTC, time zones are for formatting.
- If you need to turn a time into a string, make the formatting explicit.

```
    def get_api_time
      '2000-01-01 07:00:00 UTC'
    end

    # bad: downgrading to strings, implicit formatting
    expected_time = Time.utc(2000, 1, 1, 7)
    expect( get_api_time ).to eq expected_time

    # good: upgrading to objects, format is irrelevant
    expected_time = Time.zone.parse('2000-01-01 07:00:00 UTC')
    expect(
      Time.zone.parse(get_api_time)
    ).to eq expected_time

    # better: refactor method to return ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
    def get_api_time
      Time.zone.parse('2000-01-01 07:00:00 UTC')
    end

    expected_time = Time.zone.parse('2000-01-01 07:00:00 UTC')
    expect( get_api_time ).to eq expected_time
```

I recommend reading these articles, they clear things up.

- [It's About Time (Zones)](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones)
- [The Exhaustive Guide to Rails Time Zones](http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/)

Comment: Thank you for the lengthy and easy to understand explanation! This means quite a bit of work for me now, because we have a lot of manually created SQL queries (due to performance mainly) which now needs to be fed UTC timestamps. Also, DST changes need to be respected. Whew ... but I guess the change means better consistency throughout the whole framework. Thanks!